# How can I write cocoa bindings as code instead of in the Interface Builder?

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, cocoa-bindings, key-value-observing, key-value-coding

In my model I got an `NSMutableArray` that keeps track of a changing number of elements.
In my view I got a `NSTextField` that shows the number of elements.
The view gets unarchived from the nib file and alloc/inits the modell. Therefore, it knows about the modell and the contained array.

I established the connection as follows. In the *Interface Builder* at the textfield I added a *Cocoa Binding* "path" like this: `myModell.myArray.@count`. By this I can access the `count` property (which is a must since the array itself does **not** change).
The binding is based on key-value compliance, which I established at the model so the array can be accessed. But key-value compliance is not part of the questions.

**My question:** How can I put the binding into the source code and not writing it into *Interface Builder*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the [NSKeyValueBindingCreation protocol](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSKeyValueBindingCreation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). You send something like `[someObject bind:@"value" toObject:myModel withKeyPath:@"myArray.@count" options:nil]`.

Comment: I already tried this. To what would you refer someObject and "value" if I like to update myTextField? I tested the followings:
[self bind:@"myTextField" ...]
[self bind:@"myTextField.@value" ...]
[myTextField bind:@"value" ...]
None of the above worked though.

Comment: Nooooo, it obviously depends on where you are going to put the code, but assuming it is going somewhere with a valid reference to myTextField and myModel, the argument to bind: is the name of the binding. So as Chuck said.. [myTextField bind:@"value" toObject:myModel  withKeyPath:@"myArray.@count" options:nil]

Comment: Yes. Now I got it. [self.myTextField bind:@"stringValue" toObject:self.myModell withKeyPath:@"myArray.@count" options:nil]; Important to notice is that the textfield in IB needs to have some connection to the member variable myTextField too. (objectValue instead of stringValue works too) - Thanks guys!