# the programmatic equivalent of binding an nsarraycontroller to a nsobjectcontroller, selection, content

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, cocoa-bindings

i've split up my UI into various nib files.

now, i use two `nswindowcontroller` subclasses with `nsarraycontroller` and `nsobjectcontroller` IBOutlets. The nwwindowcontrollers are the File's Owner in their respective nibs.

the controllers are assigned in IntefaceBuilder (IB).

previously in the one nib, i had a binding from an employees `nsarraycontroller` to a single employee `nsobjectcontroller`, using a controllerkey of 'selection' and modelkeypath of 'self'

now, i try to 'bind' them via code, as such

```
- (IBOutlet) showEmployeeWindow:(id)sender;

//load a window from a nib file.
    ...

// Get the employee arraycontroller.
NSArrayController *employeesController = [employeesWindowController employeeArrayController];  

// Get the selected employee from the employeeS controller
id employee = [empController selection]; 

//now the employee 
NSObjectController *emplController = [singleEmployeeWindowController employeeController];

//Set the content object of the employee controller as the nsset called employees.
[emplController setContent: employee]; 

//Show the window.
[singleEmployeeWindowController showWindow:sender];

    ...
```

}

The problem.

the debug does shows that a different memory address for the selected employee.
ie, the line

```
id employee = [empController selection]; 
// Get the selected employee from the employeeS controller
```

seems to get a different employee.

but
i consistently see the first employee never the selected one.

the selected employee is never set as the content -- or more precisely the selected employee doesnt replaces the default first one.

Note that each `nswindowcontroller` has a `nsmanagedobject` context set via the nsdocument. its the File's Owner in the nib.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isnt it often the case. after 2 days of pulling your hair out. ask a question and bang the answer comes within 1/2 hour.

So the secret is essentially cocoa bindings, and specifically [Key Value Bindings](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSKeyValueBindingCreation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

That documentation is the typical yackademic yadda yadda. The cascading clue actually came from [a similar stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961783/how-can-i-write-cocoa-bindings-as-code-instead-of-in-the-interface-builder)

So all one needs to do is link the two controllers together like this.

```
NSArrayController *source = [employeesWindowController employeeArrayController]];
NSObjectController *destination = [singleEmployeeWindowController employeeController];

[destination bind:@"contentObject" toObject:source withKeyPath:@"selection.self" options:nil];
```

The syntax follows that of the Interface Builder bindings.

```
Bind to: Content Object 
Content Key: selection
ModelKeyPath: self
```

So its a darn easy one liner.

Binding a `NSLabel` to a Controller. In IB

```
Bind to: Value 
Content Key: selection
ModelKeyPath: name
```

In code,

```
[label bind:@"value" toObject:controllerRef withKeyPath:@"selection.name" options:nil];
```

And the options mimic those of "Raises for Not Applicable Keys" and so forth. See yackademic text for the details.

Comment: I was prepared to like this answer, but the code you give will not only give errors but is misleading to other developers. For instance @"selection.self" is wrong on more than one level.

Comment: Thanks! Just enough info to help me understand the purpose of each of the 'bind' arguments.

Comment: Thank you, binding to the keyPath "selection.self" instead of "selection" was the key for my case. Instead of "contentObject" I used the  `NSContentBinding` constant in AppKit.